# nextjs redirect default route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My Folder Structure.

```
pages
  settings
    index.tsx
    apple.tsx
    banana.tsx
    coffee.tsx
```

I have 4 routes can accessed.

`/settings/`, `/settings/apple`, `/settings/banana`, `/settings/coffee`

When I access to `/settings`, I would make it redirect to `/settings/apple`.

I've tried to use `useRouter()`.

**settings/index.tsx**

```
...
const router = useRouter();
React.useEffect(()=>{
  router.replace('/settings/apple');
},[]);
...
```

BUT, Now I am using `i18n` it doesn't work I expected.

I expected redirect to `localhost:3000/en/settings/apple` but it was redirected to `localhost:3000/settings/apple`.

My Question is how can I redirect properly to default route with keeping `i18n`?